# Android Google Play Store Native Platform

Tags: android

I just upload a new apk version in the google play store for my app, and i just observed that it has "native platforms" written on this new apk version,

Is this normal? What does the list of native platform means? Would it run on all android devices >= icecream sandwich 4.0?

Old apk versions doesn't have this native platform label.[image]

Comment: I have a similar issue and am interested in the answer

Comment: I got this issue now. and all devices cannot update to the new apk. It says "Your device is not compatible with this version"

Answer (score 3):

Check if you recently added a new library that has dependencies with native libs (As for example realm library does)